# how to groupby and filter in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have following dataframe in pandas

```
   from_exp     to_exp     salary
   5            7          10to12
   5            7          15to20
   0            3          1to3
   2            5          4to6
   5            9          7to8
   5            10         10to12
```

I want to see whar are the different salary ranges for `from_exp` is 5 years.

Desired dataframe

```
   from_exp       salary_range      count
   5              10to12            2       
   5              15to20            1
   5              7to8              1
```

I am doing following in pandas but it is not working.

```
df.groupby(['from_exp','salary_range']).filter(
           lambda x : x['from_exp'] == '5'
           )['salary'].size()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to filter first, then group. You can use `query` to do everything in a single line:

```
(df.query('from_exp == 5')
   .groupby(['from_exp', 'salary'], as_index=False)
   .count())

   from_exp  salary  to_exp
0         5  10to12       2
1         5  15to20       1
2         5    7to8       1
```

Grouping on "from_exp" here is unnecessary because of the pre-filtering step, but I've done it here to reproduce your expected output.

If you're not particular on "from_exp" as the first column, use `value_counts` instead:

```
(df.query('from_exp == 5')['salary']
   .value_counts()
   .reset_index()
   .set_axis(['salary_range', 'count'], axis=1, inplace=False))

  salary_range  count
0       10to12      2
1       15to20      1
2         7to8      1
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this way to name the column as `count`

```
df.groupby(['from_exp','salary']).to_exp.count().loc[(5), :].reset_index(name='count')


Out[445]:
   from_exp  salary  count
0         5  10to12      2
1         5  15to20      1
2         5    7to8      1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this to get your desired output:

```
df = df[df.from_exp == 5].groupby(['from_exp','salary']).agg({'salary':'count'}).rename(columns={'salary':'count'})
df = df.reset_index().rename(columns={'salary':'salary_range'})

print(df)
```

The output is:

```
   from_exp salary_range  count
0       5.0       10to12      2
1       5.0       15to20      1
2       5.0         7to8      1
```